# Unable to retrieve data from list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm designing a WinForms desktop application using C#.Net and MSSQL server. In the following class I read read the data from a stored procedure using `sqlDataReader` and I insert it in a `List<>`.

Later I want to show the list values in `textboxes`. My problem is  that nothing is shown in the texboxes when I retrieve data from the list.

My stored procedure:

```
create proc spDispMaterialPrice
@materialName nvarchar(100)
as
begin 
select unitPrice,carbohydrate,protein,fat,humidity,minerals from materialPrice where 
materialName = @materialName
end
```

Class:

```
    //display data retrived according to material combobox to user when form loads
    public List<string> displayMaterial()
    {
        List<string> materialList = new List<string>();
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["secaloFormulaCS"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conString))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spDispMaterialPrice", sqlCon))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("materialName", MaterialName);                
            SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlDr.Read())
            {
                materialList[0] = sqlDr["unitPrice"].ToString();
                materialList[1] = sqlDr["carbohydrate"].ToString();
                materialList[2] = sqlDr["protein"].ToString();
                materialList[3] = sqlDr["fat"].ToString();
                materialList[4] = sqlDr["humidity"].ToString();
                materialList[5] = sqlDr["minerals"].ToString();
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
            sqlCon.Dispose();
        }
       return materialList;
    }
}
```

}

winform :

```
        private void AppForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.materialPriceTableAdapter.Fill(this.secaloFormulaDataSet.materialPrice );
        //panel1.Hide();

        Classes.Prices prices = new Classes.Prices(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        List<string> items = prices.displayMaterial();
        textBox3.Text = items[0];
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with your debugger to see if `materialList` is being assigned with values and what those values are?

Comment: how can i exactly do this ?

Comment: You get an exception don't you?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, make sure your project is set to debug. Set a breakpoint in your code by clicking in the margin to the left of the line of code where you want to break. Run your project by clicking the little green play icon in your toolbar (or press F5). Execution will stop at your breakpoint and you can inspect your variables, step through the code, etc. Again, this is assuming you are using Visual Studio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a List as if it is an array. Without changing to much of your code with the following change your code might work if there is one record selected from your table, otherwise it shows the last record that matches the materialname.

```
public string[] displayMaterial()
{
    var materialList = new string[6];
```

and in your  AppForm_Load

```
string[] items = prices.displayMaterial();
```

Read the [Commonly Used Collection Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0ytkdh4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from [MSDN Development Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172157%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I have changed my code according to your and it works , but why?

Comment: @AlirezaX: Because to add an item to a list, you'd have to use `materialList.Add("String")`